# How did the Joint Committee on Taxation calculate the distribution of individual income tax rate increases for the Tax Cuts and Jobs Act of 2017

Tags: taxation, united-states

According to the Joint Committee on Taxation's JCX-68-17 Distributional Effects Of The Conference Agreement For H.R.1, The "Tax Cuts And Jobs Act", there will be a significant increase in income tax for tax brackets under $50,000.

In the chart titled DISTRIBUTIONAL EFFECTS OF THE CONFERENCE AGREEMENT FOR H.R.1, THE "TAX CUTS AND JOBS ACT" on the fifth page, it claims that by 2027 the tax bracket at $20,000-30,000 will have a 26.6% increase in Federal Taxes. Does anyone know how this increase was calculated. I'm having trouble finding what was referenced in the H.R.1 — 115th Congress (2017-2018) resolution to come up with these values.